# Deleting specific rows from all tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with a lot of tables.
In each table there is a column named "LicenseID" (bigint). How can I delete all rows, from all tables, that contain the value "2" in the column "LicenseID" ?
Best regards!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: you need to show your efforts.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies.
I'm using Microsoft SQL server database. Also, I need to remove rows from ALL the tables (rows contain value 2 in column "LicenseID"). BTW I don't mean values like 22,32,etc... Just the absolute value of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned which database are you working with.

I assume it is SQL Server 
First check your result with following query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LicenseID LIKE '%2%'
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE Contains(LicenseID, 2) > 0
```

Then Delete all those rows with above condition.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE LicenseID LIKE '%2%'
```

or

```
 DELETE FROM table WHERE  Contains(LicenseID, 2) > 0
```

I have not tested it and don't know what type of database are you using. Answer can be little different in different databases.

Comment: He wants something to be adjusted to all of his DB tables, not one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to generate the delete statements dynamically. 
Something like this should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max) = ''

SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'DELETE FROM '+ TABLE_NAME +' WHERE LicenseID = 2; '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'LicenseID'

EXEC(@Sql)
```

The reason I've used `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and not `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` is to prevent an error in case there is a table that doesn't contain the `LicenseID` column.